# Visual C++ MFC application Click on a drawn line and pull from the click point

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I have a Visual C++ 2008 MDI application where I can place circles and lines on the viewing area. Is it possible after I have placed a line, to select it and pull from the click point so that the line bends in an angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no MFC method to check if a line is selected, you must manually verify if mouse coords are within the rectangle containing the line (as done in the `CDrawObj::HitTest` method of the DrawCli MFC example pointed in the orher answer).

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. Since you are using MFC you can study the DRAWCLI program in the MFC samples, which is a drawing program that supports editing figures with the mouse.